# How to copy SQL log shipping files to AWS EC2 instance

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2, log-shipping

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and would like to log ship from my local data center SQL instance to a log shipping target SQL Server running in AWS EC2.

What is the best way to copy the log ship files from the local SQL Server to the remote EC2 instance?

I have seen plenty of 'how to copy a file to EC2' solutions, but am wondering what is the best method for **continuous unattended file copying** (such as SQL Server T-Log files every 15 minutes).

Comment: I would recommend searching on dba.stackexchange.com as there is probably an answer for this there.

Comment: Thanks, Zane.  Didn't know until now that there was a dba.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing this today using an S3 bucket and AWS CLI with the sync command. You have to configure AWS on each machine and make sure the credentials file is under the user folders of the account that the SQL Agent is running under. The simply add the Powershell call as a step in the SQL LS job to either put or get the files depending on the machine you are on (local or EC2). I also recommend staggering the EC2 machine job so it runs ~5 mins after the LS job on the source server.